# Passing python script variables as an argument to magic command

Tags: python, ipython

I do have a py file and I'm running a py script inside it with `%run` magic command. I'm sending 'os.path' variable to magic command but it seems that it can't interpret it as expected. Here is the code:

```
groups=['G1','G2','G3','G4','G5','G6','G7','G8']
classes=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
for group_id in groups:
    for class_id in classes:            
        src_path = os.path.join('8fold',group_id,'test',class_id)
        dst_path = os.path.join('aligned_images','valid',group_id,class_id)
        %run align_images.py  {src_path} {dst_path}
```

However it ends up with error :

`OSError: [WinError 123] the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'aligned_images\\valid\\G1\\0\r'`

The last part have `0\r'` which should be `\0`.

Comment: maybe first check `print(src_path, dst_path)` to see what you get in variables

Comment: @furas they look as just as intended. for instance `8fold\G1\test\0`

Comment: maybe you should do it without `%run` - you can't use `%run` in normal script. Maybe code inside `aligned_images`  you should put in function so you could `import` this function and run it with arguments `aligned_images.my_function(src_path, dst_path)`

Comment: I tried `%run` with variables and I can't recreate this problem. But I run it on Linux and maybe it works in different way.

Comment: @furas Yeah this could be a Windows specific problem. It treats last character as an escape char or something.